# A strong maximum principle for varifolds of arbitrary codimension

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, geometric-measure-theory

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold and $N$ a hypersurface in $M$. Let $p \in N$ and $\kappa_1 \leq \cdots \leq \kappa_{n-1}$ be the principal curvatures of $N$ at $p$ with respect to a normal $\nu$ to $N$ at $p$. For $1\leq k < n$ it is said that $N$ is $k$-*mean convex* at $p$ with respect to $\nu$ if $\kappa_1 + \cdots + \kappa_k \geq 0$ and *strictly* $k$-*mean convex* if $\kappa_1 + \cdots + \kappa_k > 0$.

Now assume that $N$ is two sided and let $\Sigma$ be a connected $k$-dimensional minimal surface which lies on one side of $N$ and assume that $N$ is everywhere $k$-mean convex with respect to the normal pointing towards the side containing $\Sigma$. Then the following strong maximum principle is known: Either $\Sigma \cap N = \emptyset$ or $\Sigma \subseteq N$. (See [Jorge and Tomi](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1024791501324).) Does the same strong maximum principle hold for stationary $k$-varifolds with connected support? This is known when $k = n-1$ and in [this paper](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cag/2010/0018/0003/CAG-2010-0018-0003-a001.pdf), White shows that a stationary $k$-varifold can not touch $N$ at a point where it is strictly $k$-mean convex (with respect to a normal pointing toward the side on which the varifold lies).

Comment: This isn't an answer, but if it isn't mentioned in White's paper, then it probably isn't known.  I would also lean towards it possibly not being true (or at least quite difficult to prove) as the example White gives showing the result holds in codimension one only for integer multiplicity suggests there is some degree of regularity required and this is harder in higher codimension.